# Show only friends' comments in Facebook Social comments plugin fb:comments

Tags: facebook

If a person enters my website he should see only his friends'comments in the fb:comments social plugin ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ ).

Is this achievable?

Comment: As you can see in the comments I left to Fabio's answer, pretty much everything I could. It seems that the options to limit visibility are no longer present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Although is on the documentation of facebook, with the new version of the comments social plugin this option is nowhere to be found. Unless there's some metatag not documented that allows that, every comment made on comments social Plugin will be public.
Making the comment only available to friends: **is up to the user and his privacy settings**

```
Moderation tools

Admins can choose to make the default for new comments entered either “visible to everyone” or “has limited visibility” on the site (i.e., the comment is only visible to the commenter and their friends), to help mitigate irrelevant content.

Admins can also blacklist words and ban users. If a new comment is published from a banned user or contains a blacklisted word, this comment will automatically have limited visibility.

To moderate, you need to list yourself as an admin. To do this, simply include open graph meta tags on the URL specified as the href parameter of the plugin. These tags must be included in the <head> of the document. Include:

<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
To add multiple moderators, separate the uids by comma without spaces.

If your site has many comments boxes, we strongly recommend you specify a Facebook app id as the administrator (all administrators of the app will be able to moderate comments). Doing this enables a moderator interface on Facebook where comments from all plugins administered by your app id can be easily moderated together. You can choose to specify either fb:app_id or fb:admins, but not both. This tag should be specified in the <head>.

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
You can moderate comments from just this plugin inline. If you have specified your app id as the admin, you can moderate all your plugins at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments.

When you implement multiple comments boxes on your site and tie them together using an app_id, the moderation settings you choose will apply to all your comments boxes. For example, changing the moderation setting to 'has limited visibility' will affect all comments boxes under the same app_id. If you need to apply different moderation paradigms in different areas of your site, you should use two or more app_ids. You may then apply different moderation settings each group of comments boxes.
```

Source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Yeah, I read the documentation but I did not find a way to do what I need.

Comment: Really?! You must be kidding me I even quoted the text that says how can you do that

Comment: I enabled 'moderation' on my website but I can't find the “visible to everyone” or “has limited visibility” options in that menu. In global settings I see: "Cannot edit global settings or moderation mode without fb:app_id"

Comment: If you go to here you don't see nothing? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments If you don't, create an app on facebook developers and copy the app id to your page <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>

Comment: I did all this but I still can't find the visibility options anywhere :( .

Comment: Yes. Actually I had one before doing this. Seems that I'm not the only one having this issue though. Many people can't find these settings ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078015/limiting-the-visibility-of-comments-in-the-comments-social-plugin ) .

Comment: I've noticed that, I've also created an app right now to test this and you're right information is no longer available I think since the new version of comments social plugin you can't do this anymore. Now every comment you do there is always public. Once again documentation of facebook is deprecated. I'm going to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is actually still possible to set the comments box to "has limited visibility" -- on the moderation dashboard, under Settings > Moderation Mode, select "Let me approve each comment before it appears." If you never approve anything, users will only be able to see their friends' comments.